# Settings location on Central Admin

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

I am getting validation error when trying to run the Migration Assessment Tool. To make sure that I am meeting all the prerequisites in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/overview-of-the-sharepoint-migration-assessment-tool), I am trying to understand which settings on the Central Admin is the following item referring to:

> The account also needs explicit Full Control permissions on both
> Operations > Administrators and Sharing > Permissions on the User
> Profile service application

I looked hard, but could not find any "Operations" and "Sharing" settings under **User Profile** on the **Service Applications** page: _admin/ServiceApplications.aspx

I'll appreciate any leads. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Service Applications, highlight the UPSA, then go to the ribbon. The *section* name is Operations/Sharing, so ignore that. You'll see two obvious buttons: 'Administrators' and 'Permissions'.

Comment: Thank you Trevor for confirming my suspicion. I have made sure that the server farm is in those sections with Full Control permissions. Still I am getting the validation error. I will post that question separately. But thank you very much for now!